# scope of pointers to (local) objects declared within a for loop

Tags: c++, loops, stack, for-loop

I'm not sure if the snippet of C++ code below is legitimate or not:

```
std::vector<int*> myints;
for (int i = 0; i<N; i++) {
   int j = i;
   myints.push_back(&j);
 }

 for (int i=0; i<myints.size(); i++) cout<<*(myints[i])<<endl;
```

How does the compiler handle this ? I understand the variable *j* itself goes out of scope when exiting the for loop but will an integer be locally allocated N times on the stack so that the int objects pointed to by the elements in the vector remain valid outside the loop ?

Many Thanks !
-bert

Comment: What is your goal here? Why do you have `vector< int * >` as opposed to `vector< int >`?

Comment: What just meant as an example, int could have been any oject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the block ends, the compiler stops caring about the memory that was previously reserved for them. But even if nothing else disrupts that, you have another problem: all the `int*`s in the `vector<int*>` point to the same memory location, so they all have the final value of `i`.

Comment: Hmm, but when I run this, I get what I'd naively expect, i.e. values of 0, 1, 2, ... are printed. Is this because the compiler unrolls the loop if N is known or somethink like that ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends (as usual) on compiler's implementation.

You will probably get all pointers pointing to the same location with N's latest value on its pointed direction.